# change your page constantly (like cps in cookie clicker)

Tags: javascript, html

You may know cookie clicker. In this game you earn "money" automaticly every second. How can I achieve this (constantly update my page) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById(element).innerHTML` to update the contents of an element. 

If you are referring to doing it constantly attach it to a [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).